# Bidirectional one-to-many with one as owning side

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, bidirectional

Is there no way of making the 'one' the owner side of a one-to-many relationship? Every single sample has `mappedBy` in `@OneToMany`. Even the answer to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633708/hibernate-bi-directional-one-to-many-with-one-as-parent) has that.

I want the one side to be the owning side because when I add a many/child, I also change some information on the one/parent, and I want just to update the parent, for code simplicity and to ensure that it all goes in the same ACID transaction.

But I just can't make it work. Hibernate keeps complaining about

> Repeated column in mapping for entity

My entities:

```
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = EAGER, cascade = {ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private final Set<Child> children = new HashSet<>();

}

public class Child {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Parent parent;

}
```

Comment: Were you able to make it work? I'm running into the exact same issue.

Answer (score 1):

> To solve Repeated column in mapping for entity error.

You can remove the `nullable=false` from `@JoinColumn` annotation as below:

Instead of

```
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
```

try with

```
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
```

But if you want to retain `nullable=false`, then

either remove `private Parent parent;` declaration from the `Child` class

or

make it transient either using `@Transient` annotation or `private transient Parent parent;`

Comment: You're partially right. I had to replace `nullable=false` with `insertable = false, updatable = false`

Comment: @user384729 That's a good point. By including `insertable = false, updatable = false` it doesn't fire the extra update queries.

Answer (score 0):

What you have

```
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
```

is no different from

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
```

on the face of it. What is your motivation for doing it?

EDIT: Yes, ok. There is a difference in how you persist with a bidirectional relationship. You have to set the parent if you use `mappedBy`, and you don't have to set the parent if you use `@JoinColumn`, but only if you remove the `,`insertable = false, updatable = false`, so I'm not sure why there was a discussion about having to include those. Also, I'm not sure why you are having the hibernate repeated column error, I didn't get anything like that. It should be noted that the CascadeType.ALL is required for child to be saved without having to set the parent.

Comment: This is very disturbing, I hope it's a misunderstanding; otherwise I'm very wrong.

I think that what I have (your first code snippet), makes my `Parent` the owning side of the relationship. Thus, I don't need to manually persist a new `Child`. I can just add it to the parent and update the parent.

With your second snippet, `Child` would be the owning side. I would need to do `child.setParent(parent)` and manually persist it, childDao.save(child)`.